# Mensagem de alert Bootstrap no cabeçalho da pagina

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, visual-studio-code

Estou usando Alerts do Bootstrap 4 para mensagem de "Usuario ou senha inválidos", a mensagem esta aparecendo, porém no final da pagina, preciso rolar a pagina para baixo um pouco para ver.

Gostaria de inserir o Alert no cabeçalho da pagina ou no minimo dentro do form de login.

Segue código da pagina de login:

```html
<form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" action="valida.php">
     <span class="login100-form-logo">
      <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
     </span>
     <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
      Entrar
     </span>
     <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
      <input id="user" class="input100" type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Usuário">
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
      <input id="senha" class="input100" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
      <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">
       Login
      </button>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <p class="text-center text-danger">
   <?php if(isset($_SESSION['loginErro'])){
    echo $_SESSION['loginErro'];
    unset($_SESSION['loginErro']);
   }?>
  </p>
  <p class="text-center text-success">
   <?php 
   if(isset($_SESSION['logindeslogado'])){
    echo $_SESSION['logindeslogado'];
    unset($_SESSION['logindeslogado']);
   }
   ?>
```

Codigo do arquivo Valida.php

```html
//Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
  if(isset($resultado)){
   $_SESSION['user'] = $resultado['userid'];
   $_SESSION['senha'] = $resultado['senha'];
    header("Location: pginicial.php");
 
  }else{    
   $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Usuário ou senha Inválido</div>";
   header("Location: index.php");
  }
 }else{
  $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Usuário ou senha Inválido</div>";
  header("Location: index.php");
 }
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você colocar os `<p>` das mensagens no local onde deseja. Você está colocando após o formulário, aí vai aparecer abaixo dele mesmo.

Por exemplo, você poderia colocar após o span onde tem a palavra "Entrar", pois assim fica bem visível ao usuário:

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div>
         <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" action="valida.php">
            <span class="login100-form-logo">
               <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
               Entrar
            </span>
            <p class="text-center text-danger">

               <?php if(isset($_SESSION['loginErro'])){
                    echo $_SESSION['loginErro'];
                    unset($_SESSION['loginErro']);
            }?>
            </p>
            <p class="text-center text-success">
               <?php 
               if(isset($_SESSION['logindeslogado'])){
               echo $_SESSION['logindeslogado'];
               unset($_SESSION['logindeslogado']);
               }
               ?>
            </p>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
               <input id="user" class="input100" type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Usuário">
               <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
               <input id="senha" class="input100" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">
               <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
               <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">
                  Login
               </button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema.